# The exterior Lebesgue measure for the image of Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz with constant $M\geq 0$.

How to prove that  for $E\subset \mathbb R$

$|f(E)|_e \leq M |E|_e$ ?

Here

$|A|_e:=\inf \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n-a_n): A\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[a_n,b_n]\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\lvert E\rvert_e$? How can you use the Lipschitz continuity to estimate $\lvert f(E)\rvert_e$ with that definition?

Comment: Right. And can you see some relation between coverings of $E$ by intervals and coverings of $f(E)$?

Comment: If $ E\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(a_n,b_n)$ then $ f(E)\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f(a_n,b_n)$.

Comment: And what can you say about $f((a_n,b_n))$?

Comment: By continuity $f$ on $[a_n,b_n]$ we have $f(a_n,b_n) \subset f([a_n,b_n])=[f(c_n),f(d_n)] $ for some $c_n,d_n\in [a_n,b_n]$ and by the Lipschitz condition

$|f(d_n)-f(c_n)| \leq M |d_n-c_n| \leq M (b_n-a_n)$.

Comment: Good. Then you can pretty much wrap it up and have shown the desired inequality.

Comment: You should convert that edit to an answer.

Comment: @Daniel  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,b_n]$. Then
 $f(E)\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f([a_n,b_n])$.

By continuity $f([a_n,b_n])=[f(c_n),f(d_n)]$ for some $c_n,d_n \in [a_n,b_n]$. By the Lipschitz continuity $|f(d_n)-f(c_n)| \leq M |d_n-c_n| \leq M (b_n-a_n)$.

Now
$$
|f(E)|_e \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(d_n)-f(c_n)|\leq M \sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n-a_n)
$$
Since the sequence $([a_n,b_n])$ covering $E$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
|f(E)|_e\leq M |E|_e.
$$